# How to find out which assembly caused a specific assembly to be in the bin folder?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, visual-studio-2022

I have a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll version 3.0 which is old and has a vulnerability. I am trying to find which assembly is dependent on it. First I manually expanded every referenced package to the bottom children in every project and I couldn't find it. I probably missed it plus this is not a good reliable way.

I ran 'dotnet list package --include-transitive'. It showed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer in a couple projects but it doesn't show which assembly is dependent on it.

This is a new .NET 6 project I created with the latest of the packages so I am surprised to see this old assembly in there.

What's a good way to find out the dependent assembly?

Comment: I believe the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) tool would show that, though I haven't used it in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You could try tracking it through MSBuild.  The output from the ResolveAssemblyReference (RAR) task indicates how each dependency is required.  Do `dotnet build -bl` or `msbuild /bl` then open the msbuild.binlog using https://msbuildlog.com/.

Find the result of the ResolveAssemblyReference task (there's a shortcut to search for this, `$rar`).  Expand the node for the task, and the node labeled "Results".  Search there to see how the dependency was resolved (you might be able to find it quickly using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer under($rar)` as your search term).

If it's a Primary Reference or Unified Primary Reference, then your project referenced it directly; otherwise if it's a Dependency or Unified Dependency, then expanding that node should show the details of which other assemblies required it.

A more concise search might be `required by under(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer)` but I'm not sure how close that will get you to the results.  If it is a primary reference, then there might not be any matches for that search query.